# How to use Regex to grab sentence, avoid tags

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of questions of the form:

```
<iiiihhiii? (end of line )
```

I want to make sure HTML tags are avoided.

I tried a regex:

```
<[^>]+\?
```

using http://www.pythonregex.com/.

here is the output:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("<[^>]+/?",re.UNICODE|re.DOTALL|re.VERBOSE)
>>> r = regex.search(string)
>>> r
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x87e2915436c23d50>
>>> regex.match(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x87e2915436c23da8>    

# List the groups found
>>> r.groups()
()    

# List the named dictionary objects found
>>> r.groupdict()
{}    

# Run findall
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'<jghjhgjhgjh?']
```

No match is occuring. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
<[^>]+[?]
```

Comment: This seems to work - I had initially made an error and got the wrong output. I changed it above. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is starting with `<` correctly, but the `[^>]` match doesn't stop at the `?` mark, nor the newline, so it will continue matching until it hits a `>` character. Maybe try updating it to `<[^>\n?]+\?` so it will match anything except a `>`, a newline, or that `?` question mark, then when it hits that trailing question mark, you match it with `\?` explicitly.